# Is it possible to update controls outside an UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

In ASP.net-AJAX, can the AJAX postback of an UpdatePanel only update controls inside UpdatePanels or is it possible to update controls that aren't inside UpdatePanels?  If so, how?

Just trying to understand ASP.net-AJAX better, not trying to solve a specific problem.

**Edit:**
I mean update from the server-side code, without using Javascript or any additional libraries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only controls inside an update panel are refreshed without a full page postback

Comment: Would viewstate be updated but the controls on the page wouldn't be?  Or would nothing outside of the update panel(s) be updated at all, even in viewstate?

Comment: No not even the viewstate is updated, I just tested it. This would lead to corrupted viewstate

Answer (score 3):

No, but what you could try is wrapping the other elements that you want to change in another update panel. Set the additional panel's `UpdateMode` to `Conditional` and then on your post back change what you need and then call `myOtherupdatePanel.update()`

Comment: This is awesome. You can essentially put every control/container in an UpdatePanel and update selectively at server side. I'm not sure why this is not widely suggested. I see a lot of client side answers to this question which convoluted

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible via plain javascript (or using jquery).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that wasn't really what I was asking about.  See my edit for details.

Comment: Didn't read you question with enough attention. No, it is not possible.